# How to hide a tweet from TimeLine in Twitter API

Tags: ios, swift, twitter, twitterkit

I am working on TwitterKit in iOS SDK. I am showing TimeLine tweets for a user in tableview cell.

User want to delete a tweet posted by others from his/her time line but I am getting following error

```
Twitter API error : You may not delete another user's status. (code 183)
```

On search I found following link

[Link](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/statuses/destroy/id) saying '*The authenticating user must be the author of the specified status*'

Can anyone suggest how to remove a tweet posted by others from user timeline. Is there any API to hide the tweets from TimeLine?

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way for a user to delete the Tweet(s) of another user. You would have to implement some custom view handling to remove table cells from the timeline.